A confusing thing about the Hermitian adjoint
There's something I don't understand here:
$$\forall |\psi\rangle\ \  \text{et}\ \ |\varphi\rangle\in\mathcal{E}, \qquad \langle \psi |\hat{A}^\dagger|\varphi\rangle=\langle\psi|\hat{A}|\varphi\rangle^* $$
Why is it $ \langle\psi | \hat{A} | \varphi \rangle^*$ instead of $\langle \varphi | \hat{A} | \psi \rangle^*$?

Yeah I think you're right, looks like a typo to me

Is this from a reference? Which page?

it's from a friend, he made a syllabus for the class and the professor approved it but he forgot to correct this mistake I guess

General tip: In such cases, check other references.

You are correct.  It should be $\langle\psi|A^\dagger|\phi\rangle = \langle\phi|A|\psi\rangle^*$.  The given equation is wrong.

Thanks, I spent like 25 minutes thinking if I was wrong or not
